# Why do fluoride molecules seem to have abnormally low boiling points?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

As far as I know, to non-polar molecules like CF<sub>4</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>,
boiling point is mainly affected by the London dispersion force.

As a result, molecules with more protons and electrons normally have higher boiling points.

However, CF<sub>4</sub> (34 electrons) has a boilng point of -128°C, while C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub> (18 electrons) has -89°C.

Also, I find it puzzling that fluorides tend to have abnormally low boiling points.

 For example (the below are all boiling points of  compounds with a benzene ring)

C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>6</sub> 80.1 °C

C<sub>6</sub>F<sub>6</sub> 80.2 °C

C<sub>6</sub>Cl<sub>6</sub> 322 °C

C<sub>6</sub>Br<sub>6</sub> 418 °C

C<sub>6</sub>I<sub>6</sub> 531 °C

 It seems to me that fluorides are the abnormal ones. Despite having a lot more electrons than benzene, the boiling point is almost the same.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136590/why-is-the-boiling-point-of-trichlorofluoromethane-lower-than-that-of-chloroform?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the various links therein.